# Regex won't return a single character when surrounded by punctuation

Tags: regex

Before I begin let me say I am new to regex, but today I have done extensive research and cannot find a solution to the following problem.

EDIT: I want to return just the numbers in all examples. But I want the punctuation excluded.

A single character string will not be returned if you surround it with punctuation and then choose not to return the punctuation.

Here's a basic example of this problem.

```
[^<].*[^>] on <12> returns 12
[^<].*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
```

If you only have punctuation on one side you are not returning then it works fine.

```
[^<].* on <1 returns 1
.*[^>] on 1> returns 1
[^<].*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
```

Here are regex's I have tried and their results.

```
[^<].*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<][.]*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<]+[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<][^\r\n]*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<]\w*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<]\d*[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<].?[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<][0-9]?[^>] on <1> returns nothing
[^<].*?[^>] on <1> returns nothing
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/gHXZl6/1 and ***with much attention*** read the explanation on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your regular expression works sometimes but it's wrong. let me first explain:

- `[^<]` means any character that's not a less than sign `<`. the `^` means opposite when put in a character class ie between brackets `[]`.
- `.*` matches any character zero or more times.
  let's look at the how your regexes work:

1. `[^<].*[^>]` with `<12>` :

   - `[^<]` can't match `<` thus it matches `1`
   - `.*` matches `2`
   - `[^>]` can't match `>` thus the regular expression engine backtracks to `2`, now `.*` matches nothing.
2. `[^<].*[^>]` with `<1>` :

   - `[^<]` can't match `<` thus it matches `1`.
   - `.*` matches the `>`.
   - `[^>]` now the regular expression engine backtracks cuz to have a match it needs to match any character that's not `<` and it has already reached the end of the string. now `.*` matches nothing and the next character is `>` that's why the match fails.

What you meant to do is `^<(.*?)>`, where:

- `^` beginning of the string (you could omit this if you want to match any part of the string)
- `<` match a less than sign.
- `.*` match zero or more occurences of any characters. if you want to be more specific you could use and you'll only match digits `\d` or `[0-9]` in place of the period.
- `>` matches a greater than sign.

the parentheses means capture these characters and are called a capture group in the regex jargon.

Another way to go about this is using lookaheads `(?=)` and lookbehinds `(?<=)` these are non capturing groups which would assert if the following (resp. preceding) characters validate the pattern given.

The regex would become `(?<=<).*(?=>)` which means match any character that's between `<>`

Comment: if you need further explanations i'd be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

The `[^<]` (any charachter not a "<") matches the 1 of 12, then `.*` matches nothing and `[^>]]` (any charachter not a ">") is matching the 2.

If you are looking to extract the digits between the < and >, your regex would look like `<(.*)>` that matches the whole set, but the parenthesis around the `.*` should be reported as a matched subgroup.  Depending on the language you are using, you would need to use the library available to extract the subgroup match.

Comment: Thank you PM 77-1, that website is amazing, I'll be coming back next time I need to diagnose my future regex issues!  Sorry for not commenting you your comment, I don't have permissions to comment yet except on my own Qs and As!